# User defined __mul__ method is not commutative

Tags: python, extend, built-in

I wrote a class to represent vectors in Python (as an exercise) and I'm having problems with extending the built-in operators.

I defined a `__mul__` method for the vector class.  The problem is that in the expression `x * y` the interpreter calls the `__mul__` method of x, not y.

So `vector(1, 2, 3) * 2` returns a vector <2, 4, 6> just like it should; but `2 * vector(1, 2, 3)` creates a TypeError because the built-in int class does not support multiplication by my user-defined vectors.

I could solve this problem by simply writing a new multiplication function

```
def multiply(a, b):
    try:
        return a * b
    except TypeError:
        return b * a
```

but this would require redefining every function that I want to use with my user-defined classes.

Is there a way to make the built-in function handle this correctly?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want commutativity *for different types* you need to implement [`__rmul__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__). If implemented, it is called, like all `__r*__()` special methods, if the operation would otherwise raise a `TypeError`. Beware that the arguments are swapped:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __mul_(self, other):
        ''' multiply self with other, e.g. Foo() * 7 '''
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        ''' multiply other with self, e.g. 7 * Foo() '''
```

Comment: How does Python know to invoke `Foo.__rmul__` and not the `__mul__` of the other object?

Comment: It attempts to use the `__mul__` of the left-hand side, and if it can't find that, then it looks for the `__rmul__` of the right-hand side.

Comment: @pst, Python calls `__mul__` first, but if it either does not exist or if it returns `NotImplemented` then Python calls `__rmul__` of the other object.  (Note that if `__mul__` raises an execption, `__rmul__` is __not__ called.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for [`__rmul__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)